# asp.net mvc radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net web form application that I am trying to re-write in MVC.  I'm stuck on how to handle bool? values.  I'll show one example, but the page is full of like items.

I'm using the bool? value named "OtherAddresses" to indicate (true) that there are other addresses, (false) that there are not, or *(null) to indicate that the question has not been answered*.  If the value is "true", then I want to show the block of code requesting additional addresses. It has the id of "otherlocations".

Please note that the radio button list has 3 listitems.

In the form I have the following block of code that works:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
    Do you have other locations?
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBL126" runat="server" 
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("OtherAddresses") %>' >
        <asp:ListItem Value="True" 
            onchange='rblShow("otherlocations");'> Yes
        </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="False" 
            onchange='rblHide("otherlocations");'> No
        </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Text=""  style="display: none" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
</div>
<div id="otherlocations" runat="server" class="row" style="display:none">
<div class="col-md-12">Please supply a list of all locations</div>
</div>
```

There are javascript functions (rblShow and rblHide) which correctly show or hide the code blocks when clicked, as well as a fairly elaborate function called at pre-render that hides or shows the code blocks based on the initial values.  Since these work, I'm not including them here.

My problem is the MVC code to accomplish this is failing with the error "Nullable object must have a value" and the page never renders.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">Do you have other locations?</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input id="RBL126_0" type="radio" name="RBL126" 
                onclick='rblShow("otherLocations");' value="True" 
                checked=@Model.OtherAddresses /><label 
                 for="RBL126_0">Yes</label>
            <input id="RBL126_1" type="radio" name="RBL126" 
                onclick='rblHide("otherLocations");' value="False" 
                checked=@Model.OtherAddresses /><label for="RBL126_1"> 
                No</label>
         </div>
     </div>
   <div id="otherLocations" 

      style="@((bool)Model.OtherAddresses?"display:inline":"display:none")">
       <div class="col-md-12">Please supply a list of all locations</div>
   </div>
```

I've not been able to find anything online that addresses this situation, though I've looked literally for days.  I've tried adding a third "input" line, and I can't even remember all the other things I've tried.

I'm trying to stay true to the MVC idea of not putting logic into the view.

Can anyone help lead a frustrated (probably stupid) newbie to MVC to the proper answer?

I left the controller code out of the original post as I didn't think it did anything, but here it is.

```
[HttpGet] public ActionResult ProspectChosen() 
       { 
         string prospectId = Request.Params["ProspectId"]; 
         if (prospectId == null) 
         { 
             return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); 
         } 
         Prospect prospect = db.Prospects.Find(prospectId); 
         if (prospect == null) 
         { 
             return HttpNotFound(); 
         } 
         return View(prospect); }
```

I have since tried one answer by replacing my radio buttons with this

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OtherAddresses, true) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OtherAddresses, false)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OtherAddresses, null)
```

but it also failed with "Value cannot be null"

Comment: That is not the way to generate your radio buttons. Use the `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OtherAddresses , true)` (ditto for `false` and `null`). And then handle the `.click()` of the radio button using [Unobtrusive Javacript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: As for the error, that is occurring in the controller (and you have not shown your code for that) - probably because you are using `...OtherAddresses.Value` somewhere in your code

Comment: I changed to 
                    `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OtherAddresses, true) 
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OtherAddresses, false)
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.OtherAddresses, null)`

Comment: and got an exception "Value cannot be null" which seems to be thrown by the helper

Comment: I didn't include the controller code because it only passes along the value but here it is      
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ProspectChosen()
        {
            string prospectId = Request.Params["ProspectId"];
            if (prospectId == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Prospect prospect = db.Prospects.Find(prospectId);
            if (prospect == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(prospect);
        }

Comment: You get that exception when you use the `Value` property of a nullable property which is `null`. You have not shown the code that throws that exception. Debug your code!